# Why is the equation of an ellipse (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1?

Tags: conic-sections

I've seen many proofs online, but I can't really wrap my mind around it.

Being a generalization of the circle, I thought its equation would be as easy to understand as the circle's. Turns out I was wrong, or maybe I'm just too stupid to grasp the geometric intuition behind it.

Comment: Clearly the change of variables $u = x/a$ and $v = y/b$ gives the equation of a circle.  If you grasp that equation, perhaps you can think of the ellipse as being a circle "stretched" in the coordinate directions.

Comment: try to see it as $x^2 + \frac{a^2}{b^2}y^2=a^2$ if this helps

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I think I see it now with this [visual link](http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/geometry/elipses/equationellipse.html) and FarazMasroor's help below.

If I'm correct, the ellipse equation would really be the equation of a circle but reexpressing one of the coordinates as a ratio between the major axis (or the original radius) and the minor axis, as can be seen in the link. Right?

Answer (score 2):

My geometric intuition, hopefully it works for you, is that if you have $x^2+y^2=1$ then you have a circle, but if you do x/a or y/b then you end up contracting or expanding the circle in the x or in the y direction. If you have the original circle, it intersects the x axis at 1 and -1, but in the new ellipse it intersects the x axis when x/a is 1 or -1, namely a and -a. Hopefully this helps you graph them too.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're driving at, but does this only work for the unit circle? I mean, how can I relate the ellipse to the more general circle equation (which has r^2 instead of 1)?

Comment: You could multiply by a^2 so then if y=0 then x^2=a^2  q

Comment: I'm so lost, what does x^2=a^2 tell me about the ellipse?

I'm sorry for being so dumb :/

Comment: @Matt24 it tells you the values of x where the ellips crosses the x axis (we set y=0 to get here)

Comment: Oh, right, how did I not see it hahaha. Ok, I'm gonna explore this a bit more graphically, and if I'll tell you if I have another doubt. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Matt24 no problem. Graphs are always helpful :)

Comment: If you'd like to check it out, I shared [this link](http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/geometry/elipses/equationellipse.html) in a comment above. I think it continues your train of thought. What do you think?

Comment: @Matt24 exactly, it's like a stretching or compressing.

Comment: And what would the coefficient (a/b) represent? I assumed it was the ratio between the major and minor axis, though I really don't quite get why this has to be so. I can definitely see that when y=b and x=0, then I get a^2=a^2, but it gets a bit more difficult to understand when y=anything else.

Comment: That's right, it's like a proportion because you're scaling things

Answer (score 0):

It is the equation of the ellipse centered at the origin.
Consider the ellipse centered at the origin and whose focal axis coincides with the axis X. The focus $F$ and $F'$ are on the x axis. $O$ as its center is a midpoint of FF' segment , the coordinates of F and F ' will for example $( c , 0 )$ and $( -c , 0 )$ , respectively , where c is a positive constant. Let p $( x , y)$ any point of the ellipse. By the definition of the curve, the point P must satisfy the condition.
$$d(FP)+d(F´P)=2a$$
where $a$ is a positive constant greater than $c$, then 
$$d(FP)= \sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}$$
$$d(F´P)= \sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}$$
and remplace.
$$\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=2a$$
simplifying it.
$$cx+a^2=a*\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}$$, then it square
$$c^2x^2+2a^2cx+a^4=a^2x^2+2a^2cx+a^2c^2+a^2y^2$$
$$(a^2-c^2)x^2+a^2y^2=a^2(a^2-c^2)$$
how $2a>2c$ and $a^2>c^2$ then $a^2-c^2$ is positive and get $b^2=a^2-c^2$ then
$$b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$
that finally it divide for $a^2b^2$
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$